# How to mock a typeorm custom repository

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, typeorm

I have a custom repository class which inherits from `BaseRepository` exported in the `typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked` package which in its turn becomes a plain typeorm `Repository`.

In my custom repository class I'm trying to mock the `create` and `save` methods but the test execution always tries to execute those functions as if it's on a real application environment trying to access a database.

File to be tested:

```
import { DeepPartial } from 'typeorm'
import { BaseRepository } from 'typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked'

export class TypeOrmBaseRepository<TEntity> extends BaseRepository<TEntity> {
  createAndSave(entity?: DeepPartial<TEntity>): Promise<TEntity> {
    return this.save(entity ? this.create(entity) : this.create())
  }
}
```

Test:

```
import { TypeOrmBaseRepository } from '@infrastructure/adapter/persistence/typeorm/repository/TypeOrmBaseRepository'
import { when } from 'ts-mockito'

describe('#TypeOrmBaseRepository', () => {
  let typeOrmBaseRepository: TypeOrmBaseRepository<any>

  beforeEach(() => {
    typeOrmBaseRepository = new TypeOrmBaseRepository()
  })

  it('', () => {
    when(typeOrmBaseRepository.createAndSave()).thenResolve(() => {
      return {
        save: () => 'saved'
      }
    })
    const result = typeOrmBaseRepository.createAndSave()

    console.log('result', result)
  })
})
```

The error:

```
ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.

      at ConnectionNotFoundError.TypeORMError [as constructor] (src/error/TypeORMError.ts:7:9)
      at new ConnectionNotFoundError (src/error/ConnectionNotFoundError.ts:8:9)
      at ConnectionManager.Object.<anonymous>.ConnectionManager.get (src/connection/ConnectionManager.ts:42:19)
      at Object.getManager (src/globals.ts:107:35)
      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.getEntityManagerOrTransactionManager (node_modules/typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked/src/common.ts:25:27)
      at TypeOrmBaseRepository.get (node_modules/typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked/src/patch-typeorm-repository.ts:11:14)
      at TypeOrmBaseRepository.Object.<anonymous>.Repository.create (src/repository/Repository.ts:99:21)
      at TypeOrmBaseRepository.createAndSave (src/infrastructure/adapter/persistence/typeorm/repository/TypeOrmBaseRepository.ts:6:58)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/unit/infrastructure/adapter/persistence/typeorm/entity/executed-message/repository/TypeOrmBaseRepository.spec.ts:12:32)
```

How do I mock the typeorm connection or repository for this to work?